# Is it possible to throw a validation error for when a picklist value is selected to notify the user if another field has value to remove it?

Tags: formula, validation

2 picklist values:

- "Prime"
- "Subcontractors"

Then if the field JV Share % has a value it would notify user to delete the value

It sounds simple I'm just not quite sure how I could formulate this validation.

Comment: Share your code whatever you are tried so far

Comment: Validation rule cant be used to notify user, its just a way of resticting user based on some condition. Please update your question with more details and also what u have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation rule will look like this and show error message to user.

```
(
   ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "Prime") 
   || ISPICKVAL(FedCapture__Our_Role__c, "Subcontractor")) 
&& NOT(ISBLANK(G_IAP_Share_JV_Share__c))
```

Comment: The only problem with it is that if it is already on prime or subcontractor and there is a JV Share % Present, you edit a different field it will not fire the validation. You must switch from prime to Subcontractor or vise versa for it to work.

Comment: I entered what changes are above and recieved error: Incorrect argument type for function 'ISCHANGED()'.

Comment: use ISCHANGED(FedCapture__Our_Role__c)

Comment: Hmm it took that but it still wont fire the validation if im editing other fields in an opportunity  and a prime or subcontractor selection is present with a JV % percentage value present. (forcing users to clean up their opps)

Comment: I misread your requirement. remove ISCHANGED(). I could understand that, you have records exist in the org where you want to validate those records also, is that correct?

Comment: Yes sir i want it to throw the validation every time someone edits any field in the opportunity when Prime or Subcontractor has a JV % present.

Answer (score 2):

You r validation rule would prevent the record from being saved and the message presented would be the "Notification"

In this case your validation rule would be similar to:

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(TEXT({YOURPICKLISTFIELD})),ISBLANK(JV_Share__c)))
```

and your message would be

> "The JV Share must NOT be populated if you have selected a value in
>   {YOURPICKLISTFIELD}"

**Note** `{YOURPICKLISTFIELD}` is a placeholder as you did not specify the API name of this field

Comment: Ah, I did not see in the title that you only wanted it for specific values. @ryan - in future put your question in the question itself and use the title to summarize the question contents